# Getting next row of table of access database every time on clicking a button

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb

I am trying to get next rows from the table of access database but I am getting last row all time.

Please guide me how to loop through all rows?

Here is the code:

```
  protected void btn_clk(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; DataSource=C:\Users\Documents\databaseb.mdb";
      string cmdstr1 = "select count(*) from table";

      OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr);
      OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr1, con1);

      con1.Open();

      int count = (int) com1.ExecuteScalar();
      int i = 2;
      while(i<=count)
      {
          string cmdstr = "select * from table where id = " + i;

          OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
          OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);

          con.Open();

          OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
          reader.Read();

          label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
          RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[2]);
          RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[3]);
          RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[4]);
          RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[5]);

          con.Close();
          i++;
      }

      con1.Close();
  }
```

Comment: When `while(i<=count)` work end you have at label last row.

Comment: How many rows are in this table ?

Comment: Why are you iterating up through all the records and overwriting everything each time? Yes, this will just show the last row because you've overwritten everything else after retrieving it. How are you intending to display multiple rows and how are you intending to identify which rows are the ones you want? It's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0):

=It`s must outside a button click:

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data     Source=C:\Users\Documents\databaseb.mdb";
     string cmdstr1 = "select count(*) from table";
     OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr);
     OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr1, con1);
     con1.Open();
     int count = (int) com1.ExecuteScalar();
     int i = 2;

     con1.Close();
```

Its must inside button click. You must make `i` property of form

```
    if(i<=count)
{
     string cmdstr = "select * from table where id = " + i;
       OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
       OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
       con.Open();
       OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
       reader.Read();
       label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
       RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[2]);
       RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[3]);
       RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[4]);
       RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[5]);
       con.Close();
       i++;     
}
```

But i think it`s may rewrite to more beauty solve.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are after something like

```
private int _currentRecordId = -1;
...

string cmdStr = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id > {0} ORDER BY id LIMIT 1", _currentRecordId);
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
using (var com = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, con))
{
    con.Open();
    using(var reader = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            _currentRecordId = reader.GetInt32(0); // whatever field the id column is
            // populate fields
        }
    }
}
```

On first call this will retrieve the first record with an ID > `-1`. It then records whatever the ID is for this record so then on the next call it will take the first record greater than that e.g. if the first record is id `0` then the next record it will find is `1` and so on...

This only really works if you have sequential IDs of course.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table is not big (meaning it contains a manegeable number of records) you could try to load everything at the opening of your form and store that data in a datatable.
At this point the logic in your button should simply advance the pointer to the record to be displayed.

```
private DataTable data = null;
private int currentRecord = 0;
protected void form_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using(OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr))
     using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from table", con1))
     {
         con1.Open();
         using(OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
         {
             data = new DataTable();
             da.Fill(data);
         }
         DisplayCurrentRecord();
    }
}
private void DisplayCurrentRecord()
{
    label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", data.Rows[currentRecord][1]);
    RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", data.Rows[currentRecord][2]);
    RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", data.Rows[currentRecord][3]);
    RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", data.Rows[currentRecord][4]);
    RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", data.Rows[currentRecord][5]);
}
protected void btn_clk(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(currentRecord >= data.Rows.Count - 1)
        currentRecord = 0;
    else
        currentRecord++;
    DisplayCurrentRecord();
}
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example. Robust checking should be applied to the rows (if they contains null values) and if there are rows at all in the returned table. Also, this is a poor man approach to the problem of DataBindings in WinForm, so perhaps you should look at [some tutorials on this subject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

Hope your table is not really named `Table`, that word is a reserved keyword for Access

Comment: Using paging here instead of pulling everything would be a much nicer solution.

Comment: I have stated that at the beginning of the answer. We don't know if the complexity involved in paging is a real gain for the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the for loop to fetch record one by one

```
int lastFetchedRecordIndex=2;
protected void btn_clk(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data     Source=C:\Users\Documents\databaseb.mdb";
     string cmdstr1 = "select count(*) from table";
     OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr);
     OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr1, con1);
     con1.Open();
     int count = (int) com1.ExecuteScalar();
       string cmdstr = "select * from table where id = " + lastFetchedRecordIndex;
       OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
       OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
       con.Open();
       OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
       reader.Read();
       label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
       RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[2]);
       RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[3]);
       RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[4]);
       RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[5]);
       con.Close();
       lastFetchedRecordIndex++;
     con1.Close();
  }
```